# how do I "install" stacks into /opt/ros?

Tags: boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good morning.  I am putting together a distro of common ros components my company may want to use, building from source to upgrade the boost version.  The core is installed after some headaches (btw where do i post how to upgrade a boost version? i cannot find an actual tutorial anywhere.).

Now i have some additional packages such as vision_opencv. It is built in ~/ros, but how do i get it installed into /opt/ros/fuerte_myversion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43691/how-do-i-%22install%22-stacks-into-/opt/ros?/) by [Bob Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2328/bob-dean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-09-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-12**:
Do you plan to make those packages publicly available? Then you can use willow's release infrastructure to build .deb packages that install to /opt/ros.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-09-16**:
To post about how to upgrade a boost version, you could ask and answer your own question.  An admin can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using  rosbuild there is no install target.  I highly recommend if you're building/packaging things to go into /opt/ros you build them in place.  That is effectively how we build the debian packages which we release.  (There's some magic to work through chroots etc in the debbuild system).

This is one of the primary features driving the development of the new build system, catkin.  To see how the debian building happens see the [rosdeb package](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_release/trunk/rosdeb/) single_deb.py is being used for rosbuild stacks in fuerte and groovy.

It's invocation is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
OS_PLATFORM=precise
ARCH=amd64
STACK_NAME=arm_navigation_experimental
PACKAGE_NAME=ros-groovy-arm-navigation-experimental
DISTRO_NAME=groovy

echo $DISTRO_NAME
echo $STACK_NAME
echo $OS_PLATFORM
echo $ARCH

sudo apt-get install pbuilder git-core python-rospkg python-vcstools -y

cat > $WORKSPACE/build.bash << DELIM
source /opt/ros/cturtle/setup.sh
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$WORKSPACE/ros_release:$WORKSPACE/release:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

#noupload while testing
rosrun rosdeb single_deb.py $DISTRO_NAME $STACK_NAME $OS_PLATFORM $ARCH
DELIM

bash $WORKSPACE/build.bash
```

There's lots of state setup on the build machine to support this.  There are people who have replicated some or all of this, but it's definitely not designed to be deployed externally and will not be a focus of development.  The new buildsystem does have a goal of supporting external projects deploying the infrastructure behind firewalls.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A proper system-wide install on a debian based system should preferably be done via .deb packages, which you'll have to build from your sources.

There is also the alternative to just copy the files there or use any other install tool/script. Eventually it's just a matter of having the files under /opt/ros with proper access rights.

catkin might make this easier in the future.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-12**:
An easy way to create packages could be [checkinstall](http://asic-linux.com.mx/%7Eizto/checkinstall/) for all stacks that are not built using bloom yet. I guess some scripting for copying all files of a package might be necessary though.

**Comment by [Bob Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2328/bob-dean/) on 2012-09-12**:
so there is no common way to make the .deb files yet?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-12**:
For the old build system (rosbuild), Willow uses a bunch of scripts. I guess it is non-trivial to set them up, but you can find them in the [release repo](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_release/trunk/). The new release system, bloom, is much easier to use, it is based on git-buildpackage.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-12**:
The most common way that exists is the release infrastructure from willowgarage. I'm not sure if catkin/bloom is official, yet.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll have to be a little more specific... The package manager (on ubuntu) places the stacks here automatically.

However, if you are referring to something from source, you will need to configure a [ros workspace](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment). This allows you to keep the system installed packages in /opt/ros, and keep the ones you've installed from source separately.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1